# How do I select multiple values based on parameters?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a little challenge. I have a report that I declared a parameter called ***Department*** that has default values like this:

All Departments, Project, Field Service, Workshop, Warranty, Marine, Contract, Manufacturing.

Each department has database entry by which I grouped then in departments e.g
Field Service has ["JOB - EXT", "JOB-AFMEXP", "JOB-LUB/S", "JOB-NBCMTU","JOB-ABB-AS"]

I have also enabled the "Allow Multiple Values" check box.

In my select expert, I have:

```
{command.Job Posting Group} in 
switch(
   {?Department} = "All Departments",["","JOB - EXT", "JOB-AFMEXP", "JOB-LUB/S", "JOB-   NBCMTU","JOB-ABB-AS","JOB-CANPJB",
                 "JOB-INSTAL","JOB-CUMNS", "JOB-W/SHOP", "JOB-WS/GEN","JOB-WTY","JOB-MAR","JOB-S/AGR", "RENTAL"],
{?Department} = "Project",["JOB-INSTAL"],
{?Department} = "Field Service",  ["JOB - EXT", "JOB-AFMEXP", "JOB-LUB/S", "JOB-NBCMTU","JOB-ABB-AS"],
{?Department} = "Workshop",  ["JOB-CUMNS", "JOB-W/SHOP", "JOB-WS/GEN"],
{?Department} = "Warranty",["JOB-WTY"],
{?Department} = "Marine",["JOB-MAR"],
{?Department} = "Contract",["JOB-S/AGR"],
{?Department} = "Manufacturing",["JOB-CANPJB"]
)
```

The problem is that when I test this (with CR10 or on web), and I select multiple values, the thing does not show the values for the multiple values. It only works when I select a single department.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I toiled for a while b4 I came up with this solution (Thanks to some friends and Ryan who made me remember that switch wont work.):

I first created a parameter field called {?Department}, then wrote a function called {@Dept} like this:

```
if {command.Job Posting Group} = "JOB-WTY" then
   "Warranty"
else
if {command.Job Posting Group} = "JOB-MAR" then
    "Marine"
else
if {command.Job Posting Group} in ["JOB-CUMNS", "JOB-W/SHOP", "JOB-WS/GEN"] then
   "Workshop"
else//etc.
```

I did not add an "All Dept" option to the formula. since I will do this programatically in the select expert like this:

```
(
   (
      {?Department} <> "All Departments" and {@Dept} = {?Department}
   ) or
      {?Department} = "All Departments"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If {?Department} is a multi-valued parameter, its value will itself be an array. With multiple values, you can no longer do a check like {?Department} = "Project" because {?Department} is an unscripted array in that case. Instead, try something like `"Project" in {?Department}` etc. for your switch boolean expressions.

EDIT: Actually, there is another problem as well: A switch won't work for what you're trying to do anyway since it will stop at the first true expression. What you need to do is build one array of all the possible department descriptors first and THEN do the `{command.Job Posting Group} in YOUR_DEPARTMENT_ARRAY`

Comment: Ok, but then where do I store the array for each department since the department names are not stored in the database